# Sessions not working after I've redirected site from subdomain to main domain via .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have a site on cakephp, developed on subdomain: dev.mysite.com. After I've redirected it to main domain(through .htaccess), sessions stoped working when I access mysite.com. Still they work fine on dev.mysite.com.

.htaccess redirect(at public_html): `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dev/$1`

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are based on cookies which are (by default) tied to the current domain (dev.mysite.com in your case). If the domain changes, then the cookie (and session) is no longer accessible from a similar domain (mysite.com). What you probably want to look into is `session_set_cookie_params` and set the `domain` to `.mysite.com` on both sides so you can access the session information on any subdomain of mysite.com

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mysite.com');
```

Add this before you call `session_start()`

#### Update 1:

Upon reading the the [CakeSession](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/cake-session#l-161) class, it appears there's a method (and static variable) that sets the host, but it doesn't look like it's used (except in the TestCakeSession class). The alternative is to use the [CookieComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html) and set `$this->Cookie->domain = '.myhost.com';` Then you can access the cookie from any subdomain. Note that if you use encrypted cookies, you'll have a challenging time getting the cookie values outside of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution about redirecting subdomains to main domains. If, say, you're moving a site that's a subdomain over to your main domain, that is, you're moving the files over to your main domain, then that's fine, BUT if you're closing-down a subdomain and wish to redirect users to your main domain, then you're going to have a canonical problem.

Let's say your main website is at mydomain.com, and your subdomain is at site.mydomain.com .
Then the search engines spidering any sites where you may have posted links to site.mydomain.com will treat site.mydomain.com as an additional domain to your main domain (like a parked domain), and you may even have listings to your main website having the url of your subdomain.

Frequently webmasters will DELETE a subdomain. BAD MOVE, because until the DNS changes propagate, the subdomain will redirect automatically to the main website, and the canonical issue will popup.

You need to be very careful with subdomains.

Comment: But this doesn't address what he is asking, does it?